# Создать переменную «resultArray» (массив)

Tags: javascript

Создать переменную «resultArray» (массив). Создать переменные «first» = 1, «second» = 2, «senseOfLife» = 42. С помощью метода массива .push () добавить в массив сначала «first» потом «second». После этого, с помощью метода .unshift () добавить переменную «senseOfLife».В чем тут ошибка.

```
var resultArray = []
var first = [1];
var second = [2];
var senseOfLife = [42];
resultArray.push('first');
resultArray.push('second');
resultArray.unshift('senseOfLife');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var resultArray = []
var first = 1;
var second = 2;
var senseOfLife = 42;
resultArray.push(first);
resultArray.push(second);
resultArray.unshift(senseOfLife);
```

Скобки квадратные были лишними при создании переменных. И кавычки в аргументах методов.